# Eclipse RCP org.eclipse.ui.ide application could not be found in the registry

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dependencies, eclipse-rcp

I am working to add the code on http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F  into my Eclipse Plugin development project.

I have noticed that I do not have the needed dependencies so I added:

> org.eclipse.core.filesystem

And it worked fine, I could import some of the needed classes. But I also need dependency for that IDE thing in the code. I have found this dependency:

> org.eclipse.ui.ide

If I add it, I get this error when I try to run the application:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "de.vogella.zest.first.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.

From what I have searched in the Internet I think that I need to add more dependencies to my project. Which ones am I missing?

I want to use that code to open file in the Eclipse editor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you have already discovered the vogella blog I would then suggest taking a look at this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#runconfiguration_problems

Comment: You may want to make sure in your _run configurations_ that you are running your Application's _product_, not an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open 'Run > Run Configurations...'

Select you application in the 'Eclipse Application' section.

Select the 'Plug-ins' tab.

Click the 'Add Required Plug-ins' button to add everything that is needed. You can also try 'Validate Plug-ins'

Click 'Apply' to save the settings